# Is there a typo in this sentence? "No una las palabras de modo que se oscurezca su significado"

Tags: traducción

I read this in a textbook on public speaking:

> No **una** las palabras de modo que se oscurezca su significado.

Me parece debe ser:

> No *usa* las palabras de modo que se oscurezca su significado

("usa", no "una").

¿Tengo razón?

Al menos, "usa" aún tiene sentido aquí, ¿no es cierto?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SPANISH**

No. **Una** está bien.  Se refiere al verbo **"unir"** y quiere decir que "No **junte** las palabras de modo que se oscurezca su significado." aunque esa frase necesita algo más de contexto para entenderse bien.

Si fuera el verbo **"usar"** la frase debería ser

> "No **uses** (tu) las palabras de modo que se oscurezca su significado." o
>
> "No **use** (usted) las palabras de modo que se oscurezca su significado."

**ENGLISH**

No. **Una** is ok.  It is from the verb **"unir"** and means (join) i.e. "No **junte** las palabras de modo que se oscurezca su significado." however this needs a little more context to be completely clear.

If you want to use the verb **"usar"** then the sentence should be like these:

> "No **uses** (tu) las palabras de modo que se oscurezca su significado." o
>
> "No **use** (usted) las palabras de modo que se oscurezca su significado."